# How to chunk List<T>?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, split, microsoft-translator

I am working with Microsoft Translator API, specifically the [TranslateArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512422.aspx) method. My challenge is the builtin limitations for the `texts` parameter:

*[...] An array containing the texts for translation. [...] The total of all texts to be translated must not exceed 10000 characters. The maximum number of array elements is 2000.*

I am getting a variable length of List elements - each of varying length (Title, Desc). I want to pass this data to `TranslateArray()` but it needs to be in proper size. How can I do this?

```
    public class TranslateItem
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
    }

    private static void chunkNorris()
    {
        // list contains elements to be translated
        var list = new List<TranslateItem>();

        var chunkList = new List<TranslateItem>();
        int itemLength = 0; int totalLength = 0;

        foreach (var batch in list.Batch(1000))
        {
            foreach (var item in batch)
            {
                itemLength = item.Title.Length + item.Desc.Length;
                totalLength = totalLength + itemLength;

                if (itemLength <= 10000 && totalLength <= 10000)
                {
                    chunkList.Add(new TranslateItem() { Title = item.Title, Desc = item.Desc });
                }
                else
                {
                    // do translation here...
                    // bug here: itemLength can be > 10000

                    // reset chunkList and add item to empty list
                    chunkList.Clear();
                    itemLength = totalLength = item.Title.Length + item.Desc.Length;
                    chunkList.Add(new TranslateItem() { Title = item.Title, Desc = item.Desc});
                }

                if (item.Equals(list.Last()))
                {
                    // do translation here...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Update: This is what I have. The code will run and split up the array in 1000 "batches" (i.e. 1000 elements of 2 columns) to conform to the 2000 array elements limit. However, it won't fix problems with size above 10,000 chars. Moreover the code is pretty clumsy - was wondering if it can be done using LINQ in a more elegant way.
[Batch method from here](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Batch.cs).

Comment: solve an easier problem. What if your list had a single element?

Comment: What have you tried? Your question is too broad as stated. You are basically just asking Stack Overflow to do your work for you. And a correct answer could take numerous forms. You need to make some effort, and then explain to us what that effort was, including a good [mcve] in your question and explaining what _specifically_ you are having trouble figuring out. Note also that your problem is incompletely specified. In particular, is it possible for any single element of the list to exceed the 10K character limit? If so, how do you intend to deal with that? If not, why are you so sure?

Comment: Example updated. It will still not fix problems with single elements above 10,000 chars, code is pretty clumsy, and it has been a long day/night.

Comment: Your sample code is still *not* a minimal example.  For example, your function, `chunkNorris()`, contains a line, `if (list.Count > 0)`, even though that test is irrelevant to your problem (your test is hard-coded to prevent `Count` from being 0).  As a general rule of thumb: If your sample code requires horizontal or vertical scrollbars, it's probably not a minimal example.  It's not uncommon for it to take 30-60 minutes to simplify your question, but you shouldn't ask 50 strangers to spend 10 minutes on your code if 60 of your minutes can save 5 (times 100) of ours.

Comment: @Brian - I hear you. I have tried to simple the example so it is easier to read. Hope this is OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, you should be modifying the `Batch` method to have two chunking rules instead of one.  That said, let's start from scratch instead.  The basic technique here is to leverage C#'s built in support for `IEnumerable/yield`.

Your goal is to batch items for translation.

```
public class TranslateItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

So, let's start with a signature.  Given some items (`IEnumerable<TranslateItem>`) to translate, return some chunked items to translate (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TranslateItem>>`)

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TranslateItem>> 
    chunkNorris(IEnumerable<TranslateItem> data)
{
```

Keep a running batch of items to translate, tracking the total length of the characters in that batch:

```
    var chunkList = new List<TranslateItem>();
    int totalLength = 0;
```

One by one, process each item

```
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
```

Figure out the length of the current item in your batch:

```
        int itemLength = item.Title.Length + item.Desc.Length;
```

If that item is on its own 10000 characters, handle it somehow:

```
        if (itemLength > 10000)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("TODO");
        }
```

It is safe to add that item to our current batch if doing so will not violate our two rules (no more than 1000 items / 2000 strings and no more than than 10000 characters).

```
        bool SafeToAddMoreData = 
            (itemLength+totalLength) <= 10000 && chunkList.Count < 1000;
```

If it is not safe to expand our current chunk, just yield the current chunk, then make a new chunk.

```
        if(!SafeToAddMoreData)
        {
            yield return chunkList;
            chunkList = new List<TranslateItem>();
            totalLength = 0;
        }
```

It is now safe to add more data to our current chunk, either because `SafeToAddMoreData` is false or because we just cleared our current chunk.  So, add more data to our current chunk, being sure to update our running total for the chunk character length.

```
        totalLength = totalLength + itemLength;
        chunkList.Add(item);
```

Repeat this process for every chunk

```
    }
```

Our loop only spits out data when it is blocked from expanding the current chunk.  Spit out the final chunk.

```
    if (chunkList.Any()) //Always be true (unless data was empty).
    {
        yield return chunkList;
    }
```

The function is done.

```
}
```